# How to append a dataframe which generates through every iteration which doesnt have similar columns as well

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix

How to append a dataframe which generates through every iteration which doesnt have similar columns as well.

My iteration generates a tfidx matrix that is in the format `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>` and then am converting that into a dataframe.

`The matrix in 1st iteration may have 2(rows)*10(cols) and in iteration 2 it might be 2*15`...

So here am trying to append all these matrices into a file, specifically dont have to be a dataframe.

```
for i in 100:
     tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
     tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform((root_text[i], tweet_text[i]))
```

output:

Expected it to be in a file, so that i can look at all the outputs at once.

Comment: Create an empty list, append all the transformed data using your loop. Then use keras's `pad_sequences` to add zeros and make it a matrix of proper shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try saving into a text file. For example,

```
for i in 100:
    tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform((root_text[i], tweet_text[i]))
    with open('outputFile.txt', mode = 'a') as f:
        f.write(tfidf_matrix)
        f.write('\n')
```

Comment: got this error `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not csr_matrix`

Comment: Also, there are words as columns for every iteration produced. I want to capture that as well.

Comment: adding this to your answer, `f.write(tfidf_matrix.to_string())` has solved the problem

Comment: okay, that was the type problem. It was a general way to write irrespective of the type as I didn't check the type of tfidf_matrix.